# Error when nesting objects in objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, razor

I'm using razor syntax with javascript to create an array of objects in two places of my code. However, one is getting an error, and the other one isn't.

Here's the one that's NOT getting an error:

```
var tableItems = [
    @foreach(var i in items)
    {
        <text>
        {
            "ItemID":@i.ItemID,
            "ItemName":@i.ItemName,
        },
        </text>
    }
];
```

And below is the javascript array it generates when render:

```
var tableItems = [
    {
        "ItemID":123000,
        "ItemName":"An Item Name",
    },              
    {
        "ItemID":456000,
        "ItemName":"Another Item Name"
    }, /* comma here doesn't throw error */
];
```

This is the other one, this following code doesn't show error, but what renders does:

```
var tableItemsTwo = [
    @foreach (var i in items)
    {
        <text>
        {
            "ItemID": @i.ItemID,
            "ItemName": @i.ItemName,
            "Subitems":
            @foreach (var s in i.Subitems)
            {
                <text>
                {
                    "SubitemID":@s.SubitemID,
                    "SubitemName":@s.SubitemName
                },
                </text>
            }
        },
        </text>
    }
];
```

The rendered array that's throwing error:

```
var tableItemsTwo = [
    {
        "ItemID": 110000,
        "ItemName": "Item One",
        "Subitems":
            {
                "SubitemID":100,
                "SubitemName":"Subitem One"
            },          
            { /* Error on this line: "Expected identifier, string or number" */
                "SubitemID":200,
                "SubitemName":"Subitem Two"
            },  
            {
                "SubitemID":300,
                "SubitemName":"Subitem Three"
            },          
    }, /* Error on this line: "Syntax error" */
];
```

How can I fix `tableItemsTwo`? I'm using MVC 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Subitems` needs `[]` around it, as it's an array of objects.

Try:

```
var tableItemsTwo = [
    @foreach (var i in items)
    {
        <text>
        {
            "ItemID": @i.ItemID,
            "ItemName": @i.ItemName,
            "Subitems": [
            @foreach (var s in i.Subitems)
            {
                <text>
                {
                    "SubitemID":@s.SubitemID,
                    "SubitemName":@s.SubitemName
                },
                </text>
            }
        ]},
        </text>
    }
];
```